# Struct variable values are altered after leaving the function

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I am struggled to write a correct title for the post. Forgive me if it is not 100% accurate.
Because, the initial issue was just freeing a `malloc`ed output without disturbing where it is assigned to. I then decided to copy the source (`encrypt_Data`) into another variable before I free it.
And then another issue arose this time. It is where I am. If I can find a proper solution at least for one of them it would be great.

**Issue#1**

```
 typedef struct {
      const char*             sTopic;
      const char*             pData;
    } CLIENT_MESSAGE;
CLIENT_MESSAGE Publish;

char * pData = "Hello World!";
char * encrypt_Data = Encrypt_Data_Base64(pData);
Publish.pData = encrypt_Data;
free(encrypt_Data);
```

If I free the `encrypt_Data`, `Publish.pData` is also freed (as they are just a pointer and pointing to the same memory location).
**Note that:** The function `Encrypt_Data_Base64` has several several nested function called underneath and it has `malloc`ed output. This is why I try to free the memory sourced from there.

And then I decided to make a copy of the `encrypt_Data` so I can then free it freely.

**Issue#1 solving attempt**

```
char * pData = "Hello World!";
char * encrypt_Data = Encrypt_Data_Base64(pData);
// ------- addition starts ------
int len = strlen(encrypt_Data);
char temp[len+1];
char * pTemp = temp;
memcpy(pTemp, encrypt_Data, len+1);
pTemp[len] = '\0';
// ------- addition ends------
Publish.pData = pTemp
free(encrypt_Data);
```

Struct variable value preserved well. So far so good.
And then I have to pass the struct to a library function (I don't have source code for it).

**Issue#2**

```
CLIENT_Publish(&Publish); // This is how it supposed to be.
//Prototype: int CLIENT_Publish(CLIENT_MESSAGE* pPublish);
```

And this time, when I debug, as soon as my current function is left and just called that one
before doing anything else, the struct value has been altered. I assumed this might be related to non-terminated string. I therefore added NUL termination as you may see in the solving attempt above. But it didn't help.

Array content before leaving the function (required block is between 0 and 12)
[image]

Array content when entering the other function (CLIENT_Publish)

[image]

Since I can't do much about the library part, I have to do something in
the part I can control.

**EDIT:**
If I get my value without using this line
`char * encrypt_Data = Encrypt_Data_Base64(pData);`

*for example;*

```
AFunction_GetPtr(&pData);
Publish.pData = pData;
CLIENT_Publish(&Publish);
```

This way, it works nice and easy. But, I like to intercept the value coming from the `AFunction_GetPtr` and use it in `Encrypt_Data_Base64` and then pass it to `CLIENT_Publish`.

Any input highly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need `pTemp[len] = '\0';` since `memcpy()` copied the null terminator.

Comment: You're storing a pointer to a local variable in `Publish.pData`. If you leave the local scope, that pointer becomes invalid.

Comment: You need to use a pointer to dynamically-allocated data. So you could just do `Publish.pData = encrypt_Data;` and don't free it.

Comment: If the string has `NUL terminator` from the source, `memcpy` will copy it. But, this doesn't help here. I tried both including `strcpy`.

Comment: Yes, local variable will be invalid, right. I should maybe make it global as that library out of all scopes anyway although I don't know if this is a wise decision to make that global which won't be needed anywhere else.

Comment: Just don't free the pointer until `CLIENT_Publish` finishes. Only then you can free memory, you no longer need.
Your first attepmt just change "use after free" to "pass stack variable reference", which effectively do the same bad thing.

Comment: `char temp` is local to the function it is in.  It becomes invalid when that function returns.   If you want to retain the memory, don't free it yet.

Comment: You can't make a global variable with variable length. You would need to allocate it with `malloc()`. But isn't that what `Encrypt_Data_Base64()` does? That's why you can just use the pointer that it returns, instead of making a copy.

Comment: @Barmar, I meant to make struct global. Because, it is the one doesn't survive once the function returns. But it is not what I want anyway.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the struct is global if it references an address of a local variable.  As soon as the function in which `temp` is declared returns, the value of temp is invalid, and your pointer to it cannot be dereferenced.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, that's true. I didn't think much about it. My general idea was not copying source value into a local variable until I loose `Publish.pData` by using `free`.

Comment: I edited my post and added my previous working code. It was before I implemented `Encrypt_Data_Base64()` in between.

Comment: From the code you show, the encrypt function should return a pointer to a malloced block, do you call malloc in that function? otherwise free(encrypt_Data) will cause memory to become corrupted

Comment: @AndersK, what do you mean by that? Are you suggesting to make a pointer to a `malloc`ed memory rather than I am using this `char temp[len+1]; char * pTemp = temp;` ?

Comment: What I mean is that pData originally points to read-only memory (literal) so changing that is not allowed in your function, so you need to either allocate/copy/encrypt in your function or pass any array that you can change.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see. But  since `malloc` called in that function, I have to free it no question on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the correct solution, but the simplest thing for you to do right now is:

```
char * pData = "Hello World!";
char * encrypt_Data = Encrypt_Data_Base64(pData);
Publish.pData = strdup(encrypt_Data);
free(encrypt_Data);
```

Now that you've made another copy of the data, you'll need to eventually free it. So you might as well just do:

```
char * pData = "Hello World!";
char * encrypt_Data = Encrypt_Data_Base64(pData);
Publish.pData = encrypt_Data;
/* Do not free(encrypt_Data); */
```

Just remember to free `Publish.pData` when you no longer need it.

Comment: Thank you William, very much appreciated. Although I wasn't too happy by freeing `encrypt_Data` after `CLIENT_Publish`, it worked reasonably OK when I tested earlier. Now, I've tested your both suggestions. They just worked flawlessly as well. And I am going to use the second version of yours which was also my very initial version. While I am also giving credits to @j123b567, @Barmar and @AndersK, I accept your answer as it is the only but working one.

Comment: This kind of looks like Encrypt_Data_Base64 is changing the passed in string literal... or where does Encrypt_Data_Base64 write its result? Or maybe a static buffer in the function?

Comment: The OP states "it has `malloc`ed output", so it seems to be writing to newly allocated memory which the caller must free.